# Comparing Character Variables

Tags: r, string, comparison, character

I would like to compare two different character variables in R Studio.
The first column (BZ_Pred) shows what participants predicted to be their 5 most used Apps.
The second column (BZ_Act) shows the 5 Apps that were actually used the most.

[image: My Dataset]

Now I would like to create a third column that contains a "Yes" if the 1st App was guessed correctly and a "No" if the 1st App wasn't guessed correctly.

But how can I compare those App names to another?

Thanks in advance!

I tried if() and else(), but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, CorinnaW! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. For this, though, likely just `x$newcol <- x$BZ_Pred == x$BZ_Act`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use the logical equality operator `==` along with the `ifelse()` function here:

```r
df$eq <- ifelse(df$BZ_Pred == df$BZ_Act, "Yes", "No")
```